# Ruby csv read first line in csv file

Tags: ruby, csv, fastercsv

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ruby view csv data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14114129/ruby-view-csv-data)

In my app i'm reading csv file, but why in view i have only second,...,n records, without first line?
Here is code:

```
def common_uploader
    require 'csv' 
    @csv = CSV.read("/#{Rails.public_path}/uploads_prices/"+params[:file], {:encoding => "CP1251:UTF-8", :col_sep => ";", :row_sep => :auto, :headers => :false})
  end
```

:headers => :false i write... but why i didn't get first line from csv file? (ruby 1.9.3)

So, how to get also first line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be `false`, not `:false`.

Comment: ok, but also, how to read first 20 entries?>

Comment: @brabertaser1992 It is better to make two questions and not ask two questions in one.

Comment: @knut i know, but here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14114129/ruby-view-csv-data i get answer, which first code is not working for me

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `[0,20]`-method also on csv:

```
require 'csv' 
csv = CSV.parse(DATA.read, {
  :col_sep => ",", 
  :headers => false
  }
)
csv[0,10].each{|line|
  p line #-> first 10 lines
}
__END__
00,a,b,c
01,a,b,c
02,a,b,c
03,a,b,c
04,a,b,c
05,a,b,c
06,a,b,c
07,a,b,c
08,a,b,c
09,a,b,c
10,a,b,c
11,a,b,c
12,a,b,c
13,a,b,c
14,a,b,c
15,a,b,c
16,a,b,c 
17,a,b,c
18,a,b,c
19,a,b,c
20,a,b,c
```

But this reads all lines to `csv` - it is only a restricted output.

Comment: ok, thank you... but please move it from here to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14114129/ruby-view-csv-data

Comment: [the Tin Mans answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14116786/676874) contains already the solution.

Comment: csv[0,10].each{|line| was what i need: he didn't write it for each loop

Comment: The first solution in the selected answer to that question is `array = CSV.read('test.csv')[0, 2]`. It's your job to understand you can iterate over an array slice of `[0, 2]` or `[0, 10]` using `each`.